# Query a value from another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api

I'm trying to extract the name of a project each time the name of an employee shows up in a given column. I set up a simple query like the following:

```
=query(Sales!4:555, "select I where R='name'")
```

Now, if I want this query to take the employee name from another sheet (same file) in which are listed all the employees. I was thinking:

```
=query(Sales!4:555, "select I where R='PMs!=$A$2'")
```

But it's not working this way.

How should I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Query syntax using cell reference](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/60221/query-syntax-using-cell-reference/60228#60228) please try:

```
=query(Sales!4:555, "select I where R = '"&PMs!$A$2&"'")
```